# Is there a way to disable autosuggest for PHP's superglobals?

Tags: phpstorm

As the title says, is there a way in PhpStorm to disable autosuggestion for the likes of `$_SERVER, $_POST, $_REQUEST` and all the other PHP's superglobals?

I often create variable with name `$request`, and more often then not I end up having `$_REQUEST`. I never use these variables, since I use Symfony, and access this data 'the Symfony way', so it would be really nice not to even see them in suggestions.

Comment: Well ... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34788 looks similar. It was marked as duplicate of some other ticket ... which is now implemented. See if you can use the proposed path there. The idea is: disable unwanted modules so it should disappear from completion results. But since `$_REQUEST` and alike are part of the core moduels .. I'm not so sure if it will work just like that (without loosing some other completion). If anything -- clone stubs repo, tell PhpStorm to use it instead of bundled one and remove such definitions from there -- this should work.

Comment: Here you can find what you'll loose when disable Superglobals extension https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/superglobals/_superglobals.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... [WI-34788](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34788) ticket looks very similar to what you are asking here. It was marked as duplicate of some [other ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5731) ... which is now implemented in PhpStorm 2017.1.

The idea is -- disable unwanted modules so entries declared there should disappear from completion results:

- `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP`
- Switch to `PHP Runtime` tab
- Uncheck/disable `Core | Superglobals` module

Possible issue is: that module declares not just `$_REQUEST` and alike but some other global variables as well which *you may want* to use in your project (check here what exactly is declared in that module: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/superglobals/_superglobals.php).

**But if anything** -- simply clone [PhpStorm stubs repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs), tell PhpStorm to use it instead of bundled one (same page in Settings/Preferences -- look at the bottom under `Advanced Settings`) and remove only those unwanted definitions from there (from your local copy) -- this will work for sure.